# JBoss session is read by different context app

Tags: session, jboss

Our application server recently met a really weird problem. We deploy same version of build into different app context for our different client, say /clientA, /clientB

Today one user in clientA portal reported that he suddenly saw clientB portal information. We checked the client A portal log, and the log shows that at, for example, 16:01:10 the user clicked a link, and then at the same time point, clientB portal log shows that the session does not have the required 'member' value. (for every link our application checks if user current session contains required 'member' value, if no we direct users to our front page), then in portal A log it shows our system tried to direct user to front page, however, instead of showing front page content JBoss sent ClientB portal information back (which can be seen from the screen shot our client sent to us).

We are using Apache 2.2.22, Mod_jk 1.2.20, JBoss 4.23, and currently there is no cluster used.  The mod_jk file configuration is:

```
worker.list=admin
worker.admin.type=ajp13
worker.admin.host=localhost
worker.admin.port=8009
worker.admin.connection_pool_size=240
worker.admin.connection_pool_timeout=120
worker.admin.socket_keepalive=1
worker.admin.socket_timeout=120
#worker.admin.recycle_timeout=300
```

Can somebody explain why it happens???